# PYQT: Set text of lineedit if an item in combobox is selected

Tags: python, powershell, pyqt5

My Question:
*How can I fill the text in a lineedit with the 'employeeID' if the ADuser is selected?*

What I am doing: I run a PS script from python, which gets me the ADusers, then I take the Output from the PS-Script (the AD-Users basically) and fill it into a Combobox (around 500 'items').

Python code(Edited):

```
# NOTE: this is not the full code, just the full code for solving the problem
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.__initUI__()

def __initUI__(self):
    self.vorgesetzter()
    self.persnum_supervisor()
    self.fill_the_combo_box()
    self.Vorgesetzte.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.display_employee_id)

def fill_the_combo_box(self):
    """Filling the combo box with the names extracted from a file."""

    subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Get-ADUser.ps1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True).communicate()

    lines = open('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\users.txt').readlines()
    open('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\newusers.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[3:])

    with open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\newusers.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
          content = f.readlines()
          for line in content:
               tokens = line.split()
               if len(tokens) < 2:
                   continue # <--- skip the empty line of the file
               tostring = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1] # <--- this is the full name
               self.Vorgesetzte.addItems([tostring])


def display_employee_id(self):
    """Checking whether the currently selected combo box name has an employeeID stored in the file."""

    with open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\users.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
          selected_name = self.Vorgesetzte.currentText()
          content = f.readlines()
          for line in content:
               tokens = line.split()
               if len(tokens) < 2:
                   continue
               full_name = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1]
               employeeID = str(tokens[2]) if len(tokens)==3 else "no id found!" # <-- support for absence of employeeID in the file, put whatever string you like here

               if selected_name == full_name:
                   self.persnum_supervisor.setText(employeeID)
                   break

def vorgesetzter(self):
    """Eingabefeld für den Vorgesetzten"""
    self.Vorgesetzte = QComboBox(self)
    self.Vorgesetzte.setEditable(True)
    self.Vorgesetzte.completer()

    font = self.Vorgesetzte.font()
    font.setPointSize(9)
    self.Vorgesetzte.setFont(font)

    self.Vorgesetzte.setFixedSize(250, 20)
    self.Vorgesetzte.move(150, 210)

    self.VorgesetzteBlock = QLabel(self)
    self.VorgesetzteBlock.move(10, 210)
    self.VorgesetzteBlock.setText("Vorgesetzte/r:")

def personalnum_supervisor(self):

    """TEXTLINE FÜR PERSONALNUMMER SUPERVISOR"""
    self.persnum_supervisor = QLineEdit(self)
    self.persnum_supervisor.setMaxLength(20)

    font = self.persnum_supervisor.font()
    font.setPointSize(9)
    self.persnum_supervisor.setFont(font)

    regex = QRegularExpression('^\d\d\d\d\d\d')
    validsuper_vis = QRegularExpressionValidator(regex)
    self.persnum_supervisor.setValidator(validsuper_vis)

    self.persnum_supervisor.move(750, 300)
    self.persnum_supervisor.setFixedSize(250, 20)

    self.persnum_supervisorBlock = QLabel(self)
    self.persnum_supervisorBlock.move(500, 300)
    self.persnum_supervisorBlock.setText("Personalnummer(Vorgesetzter):")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So what I need to do next is: If the AD-User is selected in the Combobox, I need to set the text in a lineedit with the AD-Users attribute of his 'employeeID'.

Powershell code below:

```
$s = "OU=,DC=,DC="
$User = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties name, employeeID -Searchbase $s | 
Select-Object -Property name,employeeID          
$User | Sort-Object -CaseSensitive | Out-File -Encoding utf8 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\users.txt
```

Users.txt file (I cant show you the names of our employees thats why I edited it a bit):

```
 name                       employeeID
 ----                       ----------
 forename surname            110001    
 forename surname            110002    
 forename surname            110003    
 forename surname            110004    
 forename surname            110005    
 forename surname            110006
```

I appreciate any help how this might work !

Comment: Would you mind showing us a few lines of the `users.txt` file?

Comment: To retrieve the text of a combo box you can do `self.cbox.currentText()` and to put something in a line edit `self.lineedit.setText()`.

Comment: @Guimoute I edited the txt file and I know that already, the thing is I need to match the text entered into the lineedit with the AD-Users attribute "Employee ID"

Comment: @Guimoute i need to match, for example: combotext.currentext('Max Mustermann'), with his employeeID Attribute, so basically if the currenttext is 'Max Mustermann', I want to fill a Lineedit with his 'employeeID' for example: 1111 but i need to take it from the AD so that it is correct and thats where im stuck at

Comment: Can you put the employeeID in the text file too? Then with each line as `forename surname 1234` your question would be easy to answer.

Comment: @Guimoute ive changed the output to how i get it from the ps script to the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you store the `employeeID` in the file, it is easier to solve.

What I modified is shown in comments.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
import sys
import subprocess

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Widget,self).__init__(parent=None)

        self.cbox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,300,300)
        self.fill_the_combo_box()

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(100,100,100,100)
        self.cbox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.display_employee_id) # will trigger every time you select a new name in the combo box.


    def fill_the_combo_box(self):
        """Filling the combo box with the names extracted from a file."""

        subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Get-ADUser.ps1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True).communicate()

        lines = open('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\users.txt').readlines() 
        open('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\newusers.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[3:])

        with open("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\newusers.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
              content = f.readlines()
              for line in content:
                   tokens = line.split()
                   if len(tokens) < 2:
                       continue # <--- skip the empty line of the file
                   tostring = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1] # <--- this is the full name
                   tostringcleared = tostring.replace("[", "").replace("'", "").replace('\\ufeff',"").replace("]", "").replace(",", "")           #clear the strings from special characters
                   self.cbox.addItems([tostringcleared])


    def display_employee_id(self):
        """Checking whether the currently selected combo box name has an employeeID stored in the file."""

        with open("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\users.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
              selected_name = self.cbox.currentText()
              content = f.readlines()  
              for line in content:
                   tokens = line.split()
                   full_name = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1]
                   employeeID = str(tokens[2]) if len(tokens)==3 else "no id found!" # <-- support for absence of employeeID in the file, put whatever string you like here

                   if selected_name == full_name:
                       self.lineedit.setText(employeeID)
                       break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app =    QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Two things to note:

- Duplicates are not supported. If you have the same name several times but with different employeeID, the line edit will take the value of the first one encountered (or the last one if you remove the `break`). But if there are duplicates that's an issue with your file anyway.
- Maybe you want to keep the headers we can skip the two first lines using this:

.

```
for n, line in enumerate(content):
    if n<2:
        continue
```

Comment: This looks like a nice approach, ive already tried to implement but i am getting this Errormessage:     tostring = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1]  # <--- this is the full name
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: I just noticed the brackets around `tokens = [line.split('\n')]`. Split actually returns a tuple already so we can remove them.

Comment: Also we could use `line.split()` to support any number of spacing between forename, surname and id.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, im getting another error "tostring = tokens[0] + tokens[1]
IndexError: list index out of range", shouldnt we convert it to a string? since passing a list directly to a qcombobox seems impossible

Comment: This is confusing. For me, `line` is `"forename surname    1234"` so `line.split()` is the tuple `("forename", "surname", "123")` and it definitely has indexes 0 1 2 in range.

Comment: Maybe the error lies in  `content = f.readlines()` ? Since its basically splitting the file into a list, and split does the same, if i am wrong correct me --> ive removed it but still getting the error `tostring = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1] IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Okay i have found the error, '1
\n
2
name
2
----
3'  the error is in the file, the way I receive it, the first 3 lines are the problem, its a `newline` then the `name` and the `----`

Comment: Okay solved the problem `lines = open('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\users.txt').readlines()
        open('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\newusers.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[3:])` this deletes the first three lines and creates a new TXT file without the first three lines

Comment: The next problem is: Just realised not all AD Users have an employee ID, thats when the error occurs when printing `print(tokens)`

Comment: Im still getting the error `list index out of range` dunno what it could be... :(

Comment: if throws the error at `tostring = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1]`

Comment: Solved the first problem using your solution: `str(tokens[2]) if len(tokens)==3 else "no id found!"`

Comment: Then everything should work, there is no reason for `tokens[1]` to raise a range error... my guess is that you have empty lines somewhere in the file. You know there is something pretty simple to debug: comment out the "work" code and just print the tokens at every line. You will see if one of them is faulty.`for line in content:` `tokens=line.split()` `print(len(tokens))` `print(tokens)`

Comment: Possibly `if len(tokens) < 2: print("mayday mayday")`. Is someone making the file for you? If yes we should reinforce your code against every case (missing employeeID, empty lines, etc...), if no maybe the file creation needs adjustements.

Comment: No im exporting the names of the AD users from the AD to the file myself (I am creating it via the PS script), though i just realised I got 2 empty lines at the end which are converted to a list like this `[]`. You mean thats why the error occurs?

Comment: Definitely, because then `tokens` will have zero elements and we try to access its first and second elements. But again this is easy fix, with a well placed `if  line:` or `if len(tokens) < 2:` that would work. I'll edit again.

Comment: The file-reading code is getting bigger because we really have the "read" part and the "make sure the file you read makes sense".

Comment: NICE!!! doesnt throw the error anymore, so what I need to do next is connect the Combobox when the user is choosen 'Forename Surname' and set the 'Lineedit' with the correct 'employeeID' -> the thing that I need actually... You've been a great help Guimoute, thank you very much for taking your time and helping me!!!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I would still need your help, when an item is selected in the combobox `forename` set the text from the qlineedit to `employeeid` , `if selected_name == full_name: self.lineedit.setText(employeeid)` works only on the first item selected, it doesnt change the `employeeid` according to the selection, it stops after the first one, for example: combobox selection `forename2 surname2` then 'lineedit.setText' does this `employeeid1`

Comment: We would need to encase everything after the first with in a function and trigger the function when the combo box selection changes, using `self.cbox.currentIndexChanged.connect(<name of your function>)` in your widget class' `__init()__` if you have one...

Comment: `def setlineedit(self): self.setlinedit.setText(self.employeeID)` and calling it in the `__init__` method like this: `self.cbox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.setlineedit)` ?

Comment: The last edit should be pretty close to functioning. I didn't test because I don't have the files. It's a combination of what *user9402680* provided (the class structure) + the solution we found together. Hopefully it works without too many adjustments.

Comment: Perfect! Just to conclude this, the last program did not work simply because it did the work only once (at launch) instead of every time the combo box was changed. Enjoy!

Comment: Yeah thats kinda what I thought, Ive tried to solve it with _user0402680_ code, but I just couldnt do it... You've been a great help in writing my first real python code!! Thanks again!